# DirectoryIndex not redirecting

Tags: directory, apache-httpd, htaccess

I am fairly new to apache and was a SQL Server database admin in a former life so please forgive my ignorance. I am trying to set up an Apache web server (HP-UX flavor) to conform with the DOD STIGs required for this project. I have the following items configured within my httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
DirectoryIndex dft_index.html
```

Permissions on this `dft_index.html` file are 666 owned by `root:sys` and when I browse to `http://myservername/dft_index.html` the file comes up fine.

However when I try to browse to `http://myservername/cgi-bin/` I receive a 403 error. The error log shows that the browser is trying to access the cgi-bin directory itself instead of redirecting to the `dft_index.html` file.

I have also tried to create a `.htaccess` file with `DirectoryIndex dft_index.html` and set `AllowOverride = ALL` with the same results.

Comment: Sorry for the cross post Tidalwave.  New to these boards(as in I haven't needed to use them before) and did not know how they worked regarding the multiple boards.  Thank you for correcting me and teaching me the rules.  It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive does not control *access* to the directory's contents.  Access/permissions are usually specified in the [`Directory`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) items.

If you look at the error-log, e.g., `/var/log/httpd/error.log` (different with different systems), you might see an error with this message:

```
attempt to invoke directory as script
```

for which the [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryAsScript) says

> This occurs when Apache is configured with `ScriptAlias` or `SetHandler` and a request is made for a directory path. The problem is that under those circumstances, all resources under a certain path are considered to be executable.
>
> To get around this and allow `DirectoryIndex` to work again, use `AddHandler` with `Options` `ExecCGI`, or `SetHandler` in a `<Files>` stanza.

and it gives an example which you may find useful, by turning off the `ScriptAlias`, and restoring the equivalent using  `AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl` within the `Directory` options.

Comment: Thank you Thomas.  That's exactly what I'm seeing in the error log.  I'll give this a try.